# Synchronisation using wait() and notify()

Tags: java, multithreading

I need to print the following pattern using 3 different threads such that:

Thread 1 prints "I"

Thread 2 prints "LOVE"

Thread 3 prints "EARTH"

```
I LOVE EARTH
I LOVE EARTH
I LOVE EARTH
```

using wait() and notify() methods.
I have started with the following code but it seems it is printing only once since all of them are waiting at the end of the first iteration of each loop.

```
public class MultiThreading_2 {
static volatile boolean flag=false;
static volatile String  word = "I";


public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    MultiThreading_2 m = new MultiThreading_2();


    Runnable a = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            if(word.equals("I"))
            {
                synchronized(m)
                {
                for(int i=1;i<=2;i++) {

                    if(word.equals("I"))    {   
                        System.out.println("I ");
                        word="LOVE";

                        try {
                            m.wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    m.notify();

                }

                }
                }
        }


    };

    Runnable b = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            if(word.equals("LOVE"))
            {
                synchronized(m)
                {

                for(int j=1;j<=2;j++) {

                    if(word.equals("LOVE")) {
                        System.out.println("LOVE ");
                        word="WORLD";
                        try {
                            m.wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        m.notify();


                    }

                }


                }
                }
        }



    };

    Runnable c = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            if(word.equals("WORLD"))
            {
                synchronized(m)
                {

                for(int k=1;k<=2;k++) {
                        System.out.println("WORLD ");
                        word="I";
                        try {
                            m.wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                            m.notify();



                    }


                }

                }
                }



    };


    new Thread(a).start();
    Thread.sleep(100);
    new Thread(b).start();
    Thread.sleep(100);
    new Thread(c).start();

}


}
```

Can someone please explain how to go about this problem?

Comment: Code does not compile

Comment: @JohnSnowDoesNotKnowNothing edited please check

Comment: Note: This exercise might teach you something about _how_ to synchronize threads, but it is a very bad example of _when_ or _why_ to synchronize threads. Synchronizing threads is a necessary evil. You generally should strive to do no more of it than whatever is absolutely necessary to make the program work. As a rule, if you want a program to do certain things in a certain order (e.g., print "I", then "Love", then "Earth") then the best way to accomplish that is to do all of those things in the same thread.

Comment: Yes but what if each result is coming from three different applications running on three different threads?

Comment: @ghostrider, that's an open-ended question. Why are those "applications" running on different threads? (could be a good reason, or could be the result of a bad design) Why does the order matter? (ditto good/bad reasons). If it was good reasons all around, then maybe I would put the results into a list, and have one thread sort the list and then output it after the other threads had done their work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed your code. You have put the "m.notify()" after "m.wait()" so they all wait for each other. I gently moved it before "m.wait()" and converted the for loop to an endless while loop to make the threads run forever.

**Update1**

I have updated the code so that the threads write the text for three times.

```
public class MultiThreading_2 {
    static volatile boolean flag = false;
    static volatile String word = "I";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        MultiThreading_2 m = new MultiThreading_2();

        Runnable a = new Runnable() {

            public void run() {

                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                    synchronized (m) {
                        if (word.equals("I")) {
                            System.out.print("I ");
                            word = "LOVE";

                            m.notify();
                            try {
                                m.wait();
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        } else {
                            i--;
                        }

                    }

                }
            }

        };

        Runnable b = new Runnable() {

            public void run() {

                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                    synchronized (m) {
                        if (word.equals("LOVE")) {
                            System.out.print("LOVE ");
                            word = "WORLD";
                            m.notify();
                            try {
                                m.wait();
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        } else {
                            i--;
                        }

                    }

                }
            }

        };

        Runnable c = new Runnable() {

            public void run() {

                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                    synchronized (m) {
                        if (word.equals("WORLD")) {
                            System.out.println("WORLD ");
                            word = "I";
                            m.notify();
                            try {
                                m.wait();
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        } else {
                            i--;
                        }
                    }

                }

            }

        };

        new Thread(a).start();
        Thread.sleep(100);
        new Thread(b).start();
        Thread.sleep(100);
        new Thread(c).start();

    }

}
```

Comment: @ Bahadir Tasdemir Thanks for the fix..as I am trying to understand, will the m.wait() be executed after m.notify(). can you please explain the flow of wait() and notify() here?

Comment: You are welcome. With notify() you make your thread notify that it has completed its work. With wait() you make your thread to be notified. When you call wait before notify, for all of your threads, they enter to the state for waiying. As it is straightforward, there are not any threads that notify one, they are all waiting someone to notify them. So, by moving notify before wait, all threads notify that they are done with its process. At that time, if any other thread is in waiting state they got notified and continue to work. Please mark as the right answer.

Comment: Thanks man, understood the flow. But as I was debugging I found out this wont work with limited iterations of for loop. I there a way to incorporate that in the code as well?

Comment: Convert the while loops to the iterations you want

Comment: Its not working I tried with different combinations. The output is displaying only one line.

Comment: Thanks a lot man..that was quiet obvious but tricky as well :)

Answer (score 1):

`Object.notify()` picks a random thread to wake up. Your code works one time because of the sleeps between the starts, you artificially ensure the expected order of execution.

You should rather use `notifyAll()`, waking all threads, and because of that, the threads should `wait()` in a loop, until their turn has arrived:

```
Runnable a = new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    synchronized (m) {
      for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
        while(!word.equals("I"))
          try{
            m.wait();
          }
          catch(InterruptedException ie){
            ie.printStackTrace();
          }
        System.out.print("I ");
        word = "LOVE";
        m.notifyAll();
      }
    }
  }
};

Runnable b = new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    synchronized (m) {
      for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
        while(!word.equals("LOVE"))
          try{
            m.wait();
          }
          catch(InterruptedException ie){
            ie.printStackTrace();
          }
        System.out.print("LOVE ");
        word = "WORLD";
        m.notifyAll();
      }
    }
  }
};

Runnable c = new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    synchronized (m) {
      for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
        while(!word.equals("WORLD"))
          try{
            m.wait();
          }
          catch(InterruptedException ie){
            ie.printStackTrace();
          }
        System.out.println("WORLD ");
        word = "I";
        m.notifyAll();
      }
    }
  }
};

new Thread(a).start();
new Thread(b).start();
new Thread(c).start();
```

The `if` from the start has been removed, as in real concurrent execution there is no guarantee to have the expected value in `word`. Then one of the threads grabs the lock, checks if `word` is its own one, and either start waiting, or prints its text and steps `word` to the next phase, waking up the other threads (both of them, with `notifyAll()`). Then it either exits, or proceeds to the `wait()` again. This is an important part: I wanted to modify your code as less as possible, so everything happens inside the synchronized blocks, meaning that threads can run only when the other two are waiting or finished. For this lock-stepping it works, but in general the synchronized block should rather be inside the for loop, perhaps two separate blocks, one around the equals-wait loop, and another one around the set+notifyAll statements.

Comment: you are right, and here, notify() is just enough because what you need here to notify a random thread. It will notify another one when its done. The cycle will always go like this until the needed thread takes the turn. And, it will also notify a random thread after completing the needed next job. It is working, run the code on your local.

Comment: @BahadirTasdemir No worries, I know your code works. However the JLS explicitly says that one should assume [no waking order at all](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.2.2). Your code builds on the FIFO order which is implemented in real-life ([```notify```](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-hotspot/blob/master/src/share/vm/runtime/objectMonitor.cpp#L1626) calls [```DequeueWaiter()```](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-hotspot/blob/master/src/share/vm/runtime/objectMonitor.cpp#L2271) in line 1637). It would die with different order (random, FIFO).

Comment: yes you shouldn't assume any order, in real life scenarios. I think this sample is to understand threads. So the order is for the sample. If you are going to run an ordered routine, you put them in the same thread right? At the same time, when you call notifyAll(), nothing will happen but you will run the threads much more than in the notify() version: For example think that the thread for the word "WORLD" is running. It is going to call notifyAll() and let threads "I" and "LOVE". But the next thread is "I". So if you call notify() there is a 50% chance to let "I" play next.

Comment: When the thread "WORD" notifys other threads "I" and "LOVE" they will check that if the next turn is for them. But when "WORD" calls notify(), two possibilities:
1) "LOVE" gets the notify, checks that it is not its turn, waits again, and then "I" takes the turn, checks it is its turn, prints, switches word, waits again
2) "I" gets the notify, checkts that it is its turn, prints, switches word and waits. And then "LOVE" comes, checks it is its turn, prints, switches word and waits. And so on..

Comment: @BahadirTasdemir If 1) happened the way you describe, it would be an endless loop, ```i++``` in the ```for```, and ```i--``` in the ```else```. It would not ```wait()``` neither ```notify()``` as the ```else``` branch would execute. The lucky part is the ```synchronized```: the following thread is not waiting that time actually, it is blocked on synchronization, and the preceding thread (the one issuing the ) is the one which is notified. So the threads are waiting on the synchronization block most of the time. Just surround the ```wait()``` call with logs, and you will see the reverted order.

Comment: There will be only one process each time, no race conditions, no need to notifyAll()